# How to run some but not all tests in a Perl test suite in parallel?

Tags: perl, testing, parallel-processing, automated-tests

I've got a Perl-based test suite with 10,000+ tests that I would like to make run faster. I've tested using the `-j` flag to `prove`, and I have found that most-but-not-all of my tests are ready to run in parallel.

While I can work on making the remaining tests to be "parallel friendly", I expect there always be some tests which are not.  What's a good way to manage this? I would like for it to be easy to run the whole set of tests efficiently, and make it easy to mark tests as "not-parallel-ready" if I need to.

Here are some options I see:

1. [prove could be patched to support some tests as not-parallel-ready](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77238)
2. Jenkins is being used to manage the test suite runs. I could split off the non-parallel tests into their own run. In other words, give up and use two test runs.
3. Perhaps there is a way to merge two `TAP` result streams together that I have yet to recover.

I'm not too concerned with how I will manage the list of exceptions. Either I can keep a list in a file as part of the test harness infrastructure, or I could put something in each test header that would mark it as such, and our test harness could determine the list of exceptions dynamically.

( The test suite is partially based on Test::Class, and I'll also be looking at Test::Class::Load to speed it up as well. )

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution. It's in the documentation for [aggregate_tests() for TAP::Harness](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP::Harness#3). It includes a code sample for how I could write my own harness for this purpose:

> ...This is useful, for example, in the case where some tests should
>   run in parallel but others are unsuitable for parallel execution.

```
my $formatter   = TAP::Formatter::Console->new;
my $ser_harness = TAP::Harness->new( { formatter => $formatter } );
my $par_harness = TAP::Harness->new(
    {   formatter => $formatter,
        jobs      => 9
    }
);
my $aggregator = TAP::Parser::Aggregator->new;

$aggregator->start();
$ser_harness->aggregate_tests( $aggregator, @ser_tests );
$par_harness->aggregate_tests( $aggregator, @par_tests );
$aggregator->stop();
$formatter->summary($aggregator);
```

From there it looks like I could:

- Sub-class `App::Prove` and override `_runtests()`, which is where the new functionality above could be merged in.
- Fork `prove` so that it calls `My::App::Prove` instead of `App::Prove`.

Now that I better understand how the pieces fit together I can see how I might create a patch for `prove` that would add an option like `--exclude-from-parallel FILE`, which would allow you to specify a file, which contains a list of test files to be excluded from parallel testing.

**UPDATE 2012-08-16:** I have a patch for `prove` now, and have submitted it for review. You can [view and comment on the Pull Request](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/pull/3). No summary is produced after the run output. It's not clear why.

Answer (score 6):

I've now found the best solution so far to this problem. In turns out that `prove` has had undocumented support for marking some tests to be run in sequence instead of parallel since 2008. It's backed by a rather fancy "rules" system in TAP::Parser::Scheduler that allows for complex specifications of ordering arrangements for parallel and sequential test runs.

Here's the basic current recipe for `prove`:

```
 # All tests are allowed to run in parallel, except those starting with "p"
 --rules='seq=t/p*.t' --rules='par=**'
```

I have a new [pull request](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/pull/5) that adds documentation for this feature, and have started a discussion about possibly offering a simpler syntax for basic exceptions as well. See the pull request for details.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution which advertised this feature, but I could only get trivial cases to work. It's to use [Test::Steering](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aSteering). It allows me to do this:

```
include_tests( { jobs => 4 }, @parallel_tests );
include_tests( @serial_tests  );
```

With this solution, be aware:

- Before it actually works, I currently have to [patch the code to fix a basic bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=62681) with it that has remained unpatched for multiple years.
- Additional code is needed to handle generating the list of of parallel and serial tests to run.
- I didn't actually get a combined summary for my real-world test... both sections emitted their own summary reports, so it didn't really work. Maybe I missed something, or maybe it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Test::Parallel also provides an easier way to run some tests in parallel
have a look at the sample from https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Parallel

Comment: Except this doesn't build in my env :(.   Also it's uncessarily complex.  I implemented a simpler solution with some forking and builder->output in about an hour.   I would happily post to CPAN if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use a rules file for [TAP::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/Test-Harness-3.35/lib/TAP/Harness.pm%20TAP::Harness).

You can build custom rules in a YAML file (called testrules.yml by default). I needed something similar to what you describe, which I was able to do with a testrules.yml file that looked like this:

```
---
    seq:
        # tests that are not parallel-ready (will run in isolation)
        - seq:
            - t/test1.t
            - t/test2.t
        # tests that can run in parallel
        - par:
            # wildcard for everything else
            - **
```

In my case, I was using this with code that directly called App::Prove, rather than command-line `prove`. But I think it would work with `prove` too?